# Enums with data in swift

Tags: enums, swift

I would like to use java-like enums, where you can have enum instances with custom data. For instance:

```
enum Country {
    case Moldova(capital: "Chișinău", flagColors: [Color.Blue, Color.Yellow, Color.Red]);
    case Botswana(capital: "Gaborone", flagColors: [Color.Blue, Color.White, Color.Black]);
}
```

I could later write:

```
Country.Moldova.capital;
```

It seems that I can indicate the variables, but not the values, and I can only assign the values when using the enum, not declaring. Which would be the best way to mimic this behaviour?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can do something like this, which may be helpful: *(that is a very generic example only)*

```
enum Country : Int {
    case Moldova, Botwana;

    //

    func capital() -> String {
        switch (self) {
        case .Moldova:
            return "Chișinău"
        case .Botwana:
            return "Gaborone"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    //

    func flagColours() -> Array<UIColor> {
        switch (self) {
        case .Moldova:
            return [UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.redColor()]
        case .Botwana:
            return [UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.whiteColor(), UIColor.blackColor()]
        default:
            return []
        }
    }

    //

    func all() -> (capital: String, flagColours: Array<UIColor>) {
        return (capital(), flagColours())
    }

    //

    var capitolName: String {
    get {
        return capital()
    }
    }

    //

    var flagColoursArray: Array<UIColor> {
    get {
        return flagColours()
    }
    }

}
```

---

then you can access to the details like this:

```
let country: Country = Country.Botwana
```

## get the *capital*

that way:

```
let capital: String = country.capital()
```

or another:

```
let capital: String = country.all().capital
```

or a third one:

```
let capital: String = country.capitolName
```

## get the *flag's colours*:

that way:

```
let flagColours: Array<UIColor> = country.flagColours()
```

or another:

```
let flagColours: Array<UIColor> = country.all().flagColours
```

or a third one:

```
let flagColours: Array<UIColor> = country.flagColoursArray
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, although I don't think that it's ideal, it does mimmic the behaviour I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another generic example that is similar to the one posted by holex, but a bit closer to how it looks in Java. (I like it because all of the custom data is in one place). Instead of switching on 'self' in separate methods, I simply create a static dictionary that maps each case to a tuple containing the appropriate data. Then, I have convenience var's to get at the data easily.

```
enum TestEnum {
    case One
    case Two
    case Three

    private static let associatedValues = [
        One:    (int: 1, double: 1.0, string: "One"),
        Two:    (int: 2, double: 2.0, string: "Two"),
        Three:  (int: 3, double: 3.0, string: "Three")
    ]

    var int: Int {
        return TestEnum.associatedValues[self]!.int;
    }

    var double: Double {
        return TestEnum.associatedValues[self]!.double;
    }

    var string: String {
        return TestEnum.associatedValues[self]!.string;
    }
}
```

You can access the custom data like so:

```
println(TestEnum.One.int)      // 1
println(TestEnum.Two.double)   // 2.0
println(TestEnum.Three.string) // Three
```

Comment: I really like this solution because it keeps each enum data in a single line. Have you figured out how to get the compiler to check that all the cases are covered in `associatedValues`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems like enums with [raw values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_188) are limited to literal values. You may want to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

As an alternative, you could do something like this:

```
let Country = (
    Moldova: (capital: "Chișinău", flagColors: [Color.Blue, Color.Yellow, Color.Red]),
    Botswana: (capital: "Gaborone", flagColors: [Color.Blue, Color.White, Color.Black])
)
```

or this:

```
struct Country {
    let capital: String
    let flagColors: [Color]
}

let Countries = (
    Moldova: Country(capital: "Chișinău", flagColors: [.Blue, .Yellow, .Red]),
    Botswana: Country(capital: "Gaborone", flagColors: [.Blue, .White, .Black])
)
```