# How to convert HKBloodType Enum to a string

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to convert an enum to a string, using this variable:

```
var bloodType:HKBloodTypeObject? = healthKitStore.bloodTypeWithError(&error);
```

And this enum:

```
enum HKBloodType : Int {
    case NotSet
    case APositive
    case ANegative
    case BPositive
    case BNegative
    case ABPositive
    case ABNegative
    case OPositive
    case ONegative
}
```

I know that there are other questions similar to this, but I haven't found any answers that worked for me.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094984/convert-objective-c-typedef-to-its-string-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

As simple description: the HKBloodTypeObject as wrapper of HKBloodType parameter that is in the HealthKit storage.

```
extension HKBloodTypeObject {
    func string()->String {
        switch self.bloodType {
        case .abNegative:
            return "AB-"
        case .abPositive:
            return "AB+"
        case .aNegative:
            return "A-"
        case .aPositive:
            return "A+"
        case .bNegative:
            return "B-"
        case .bPositive:
            return "B+"
        case .oNegative:
            return "O-"
        case .oPositive:
            return "O+"
        default:
            return "Not Set"
        }
    }
}
```

the best way to use this extension of HKBloodType enum.
Hope lines of code above 'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a en extension to `HKBloodType` that implements `CustomStringConvertible` (`Printable` for Swift < 2), see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707744/335974