# Swift: get self.description in self.description

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to modify description output for ErrorProtocol. But this snippet, gives me infinite loop.

```
enum GeneralError: ErrorProtocol, CustomStringConvertible {
      case NoMemory

      var description: String {
          return String(self).lowercased()
      }
 }
```

Changing to `self.dynamic` type gives me a "generalerror".

Is there any way how to get just "nomemory"? Without using conditionals.

Comment: I think you will end up needing conditionals for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Swift: Convert enum value to String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701075/swift-convert-enum-value-to-string) isn't an exact match for your question, but it really covers the guts of it.  In your case, you'll want to change it up a little bit:

```
enum Error : String, ErrorProtocol, CustomStringConvertible {
    case NoMemory

    var description : String {
        return self.rawValue.lowercaseString
    }
}
```

This works because the default rawValue for enum cases where the associated type is String is the name of the case.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `String(self)` in `GeneralError.description`, you're making the `String` initializer use your object (`self`) as a `CustomStringConvertible` to make a new string. Internally, it does this by calling `description` on it, hence the recursion

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That explains the "why", but I asked for the "what"