# Swift how to use enum to get string value

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have enum:

```
enum NewProgramDetails: String {
    case Description = "Description", ToMode = "To Mode", From = "From", To = "To", Days = "Days"

    static let allValues = [Description, ToMode, From, To, Days]
}
```

I want to use this enum to display in my cell depend on indexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.text = NewProgramDetails.ToMode
```

error: Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController.NewProgramDetails' to type 'String?'

How can I use enum values to assign it to label text as a string?

Comment: You need to access its rawValue. `cell.textLabel.text = NewProgramDetails.ToMode.rawValue`

Comment: Btw No need to assign the same String to it if it is identical to its case.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701075/swift-convert-enum-value-to-string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `rawValue` of the enum:

```
cell.textLabel.text = NewProgramDetails.ToMode.rawValue
```

Answer (score 19):

In swift 3, you can use this

```
var enumValue = Customer.Physics
var str = String(describing: enumValue)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for live values, apparently. Like `avplayeritem.status`.

Comment: `String(describing:)` should *never* be used to convert anything to String, it's not its purpose and will give unexpected results in many cases.

Answer (score 7):

Other than using `rawValue`,

```
NewProgramDetails.ToMode.rawValue // "To Mode"
```

you can also call `String.init` to get the enum value's string representation:

```
String(NewProgramDetails.ToMode)
```

This will return `"ToMode"`, which can be a little bit different from the `rawValue` you assigned. But if you are lazy enough to not assign raw values, this `String.init` method can be used!

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a feedback to feedbackassistant with text:

/>

Code:

```
let test: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back
print("This is fail: \(test)")
```

In debugger:

```
"This is fail: AVCaptureDevicePosition"
```

Expected:

```
"This is fail: back"
"This is fail: AVCaptureDevicePosition.back"
...
```

So the problem is that enum values with associated values doesn't printed. String(test), Mirror(reflecting: test), String(reflecting: test), String(describing: test) doesn't help too.

</

**And here is the answer from apple:**

> This prints AVCaptureDevicePosition(rawValue: 1), i.e., not just the
> name of the enum, but the raw value too. Swift can't print the text
> version of this enum value because it doesn't have it at runtime. This
> is a C-style enum and so all we have is a number, unless we embedded
> string equivalent values for C enums into the binary, which we have no
> plans to do.