# Enum Simplicity in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following enum and it works. However, is there a way that I can simply change Int and make it String and then directly assign?

is not it the following to wordy ? `Companies(rawValue: httpMethod.self.rawValue)!` compared to `Companies.stringValue`

How could I call the following to get the String value?

```
public enum Companies: String {
  case oil = "OIL"
  case tech = "TECH"
  case government = "GOVERNMENT"
  case restaurant = "RESTAURANT"
}
```

The following works!

```
public enum Companies: Int {
  case oil
  case tech
  case government
  case restaurant

  var stringValue: String {
    switch self {
    case .oil:
      return "OIL"
    case .tech:
      return "TECH"
    case .government:
      return "GOVERNMENT"
    case .restaurant:
      return "RESTAURANT"
    }
  }
}
```

I could simply call `Companies.stringValue`

Comment: “But why the following does not work?“. It does work. In fact you can even remove the assignments and it still works.

Comment: Sorry @matt, I have fixed my question. I apologize.

Comment: How about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707744/3791245): use `enum Companies: CustomStringConvertible` and add `var description: String` instead of `stringValue`.

Comment: I still don't see the point. Please provide a genuine use case.

Comment: `enum Companies: String, CustomStringConvertible {`
    `case oil, tech, government, restaurant`
    `public var description: String { rawValue.uppercased() }`
`}`

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
public enum Companies: String {
 case oil
 case tech
 case government
 case restaurant
 }
 let c = Companies.oil
 print(c.rawValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a calculated property to your enum

```
public enum Companies: Int {
    case oil
    case tech
    case government
    case restaurant

    var string: String {
        "\(self)".uppercased()
    }
}
```